# How to skip US country restriction while post FB story?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have restricted US country to our website. So if anyone visit our site from US IP range then we will show content like "Website not available in your country".

Now My issue is:
After blocking US, we are not able to post any stories to facebook. After paste our URL to Status or "Write something..." box, it shows content like "Website not available in your country". That's country restriction content shows.

I thought of facebook uses US server to their website. So my website automatically block US. Even I try to post from India.

How to avoid/fix this issue?

Comment: Facebook have servers all over the world.

Comment: You will need to add an exception to your restriction for the FB scraper; [it can be recognized by its User Agent](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#scraperinfo). (Be aware that that would allow everyone else who sends that User Agent to access the content too.)